# Is it nesessary to set FLASH_ACR LATENCY for stm32f407?

Tags: stm32

I use stm32f407 to read internal flash.In rm book,it says need to set latency 5WS with 168MHz when reading flash, after reset latency is 0WS.But I read ST demo, and other code on Internet.None of them set the latency.Why dont they set latency or rm book is not true?
Thank you.

Comment: "Read other code" - links, please. It could be they set latency in some deep function possibly the same one the ups the clocks. If MCU runs at 168MHz, it absolutely MUST have wait states set, otherwise the thing falls straight to hardfault.

Comment: Thanks It is deep,in function sysclock, it does not use a function, but it manupulate a register.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what you just said.

Answer (score 1):

After reset the clock speed is 16MHz.  At this speed wait states are not required.

If you want to increase the clock speed you must enable the wait states first.

Comment: @ethan please will you accept this answer with the tick mark on the left?